# System with vectors that express states of the world

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given a system of $100$ different states $\hat p_i$ and a function that assigns a value to each of the states at a given time, such that: $\overrightarrow m (t)= \{m_1(t),...,m_{100}(t)\}$. I make the assumption that the values evolve in the following way: $\overrightarrow m(t+1) = B . \overrightarrow m(t)$ where B is a random $5\times 5$ matrix.

I want to show that:

> $\overrightarrow m (t) = B^T . \overrightarrow m (0)$ where $B^T$ is the transpose of the random $5\times 5$ matrix.

I'm not sure how to approach this question. Shall I express the vector in terms of the states and then rearrange? Furthermore, shall I set the matrix $B$ as a $100\times 100$ (number of states) rather than a $5\times 5$?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure you are misinterpreting your problem.  It sounds like you have vectors $\{m(0), m(1), m(2), ...\}$ that are produced by the iteration $m(t+1) = Bm(t)$ for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$. You want to prove that for all positive integers $t$ we have $m(t) = B^tm(0)$ where $B^t = \underbrace{BB...B}_{\mbox{$t$ times}}$ is the matrix $B$ multiplied by itself $t$ times.  I suspect your use of the phrase "random matrix $B$" really should be "a given matrix $B$," and I suspect you are not supposed to be using transposes anywhere.

Comment: Yes. I see your point. How would you show that  ()=(0) is true then? Through recursive calculations?

Comment: Yes.  $m(1) = Bm(0)$.  $m(2) = Bm(1) = ...$.